# Can't reload updated list into datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that I am using to display a list of objects.  These objects have several properties which are used to populate the columns of the datagridview.

To populate the datagridview, I have a function that I pass a reference of the datagridview to.  When the form is created, the form.Load event fires and the external function works perfectly.  However, when I go to reload the datasource using the same function (its actually called by an event for the reload) the datagridview fails to reload with the updated list of objects.

Here's the code for the update function:

```
Public Function UpdateDataGridView(ByRef datagridView As Windows.Forms.DataGridView) As DataGridView


    'clear the gridview's previous iteration
    If datagridView Is Nothing Then
        datagridView = New DataGridView
    End If

    datagridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    Dim bindingSource As BindingSource = New BindingSource()

    If datagridView.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
        bindingSource.DataSource = Nothing
        bindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
    End If

    bindingSource.DataSource = masterHopperList
    datagridView.DataSource = bindingSource

    Return datagridView

End Function
```

I've tried several different ways of populating the datagridview, including using a binding source (which I have above), setting a binding list, and populating each row individually by iterating through the list.  None of them work.

What am I missing to make this work?

**Edit:** Here's some of the code snippets for where I'm adding objects to the list

Initializing it at the module level:

```
Public masterHopperList As New List(Of IHopperItem)
```

merging a temporary list of objects (objects are added to it using the IList(Of T).Add method) to the master list.

```
Public Function concatHopperArray(ByVal masterHopperList As List(Of IHopperItem), ByVal hopperListToAdd As List(Of IHopperItem)) As List(Of IHopperItem)

    'merges two IHopperItem lists together

    'if the master is empty, then we can just return the "ToAdd" list
    If masterHopperList.Count = 0 Then
        Return hopperListToAdd
    End If

    'alternatively, if the toAdd array is empty or zero then we can just grab the master and return it
    If hopperListToAdd.Count = 0 Then
        Return masterHopperList
    End If

    'barring those then we can just merge the two lists
    masterHopperList.AddRange(hopperListToAdd)

    Return masterHopperList       

End Function
```

Comment: What is `masterHopperList` (what Type)?  Why are you creating a new DGV there if all you want to do is refresh the datasource?

Comment: masterHopperList is a List(Of) of a custom object.  It basically contains properties that I'm using to populate the DGV.  The creating a new DGV is there to avoid a null reference exception that I was getting earlier.  I just forgot to take it out.

Comment: What exactly are you refreshing from?  A db or code objects?

Comment: It's supposed to read and refresh from code objects.

Comment: Well, there is no "reading" there.  What kind of change are you trying to expose?  New items added or changes to the items?  Most changes should show up automatically since you wrap it in a BindingSource (you could use a `BindingList(Of T)` instead)

Comment: I suppose I should have used loading instead of "reading".  Anyway, I'm trying to expose additions, changes and deletions.

Comment: @Plutonix I've also tried wrapping the list in a `BindingList(Of T)` before setting that as the DGV's data source, with no difference in behavior.

Comment: Adds and Deletes should display with no help at all.  Changes to the items, like `Foo.Name` changing from "Ziggy" to "Zalgo" needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class.  Either a BindingSource or BindingList will pick ip the notifications.

Comment: Why a function when your are passing a `DataGridView` by ref? Doesn't make sense to me... Make it a method... Also if it is an update why set it's AutoGenerateColumns every time?

Comment: What is this mysterious object?  Is it a class you wrote or something else?  There is not much worthwhile in that method, you just need to modify/change the datasource, not recreate the DGV or even pass it

Comment: @Plutonix just what I was thinking ;)

Comment: @Plutonix yes, a class I wrote.  The approach I am trying to take toward this is that I want to update the underlying list of code objects using other forms, and then replace the dgv's datasource with the new list of code objects, which should update what the DGV is displaying (at least that's how I understand the way DGV's work).

Comment: It sounds like the way you are using the list is messed up if adds and deletes arent reflected.  Adding and Removing items doesnt involve a "new list" which may be the real problem (aside from `INotifyPropertyChanged`).  Show the code for when an item is added.

Comment: @Codexer I'm passing it byRef for two reasons.  One, the method is in a separate module from the UI class that houses the DGV, so I need a way to access it.  Two, as I understand it, DGV objects are references to the actual object, rather than the objects themselves, so it makes little sense to pass it byVal instead.  The `AutoGenerateColumns` property and the fact that it's a function is just sloppy coding on my part, which I'll fix later.

Comment: You have the same issue with `concatHopperArray`: you are not just adding or deleting from it, you are creating new ones via return - or *different* ones via `hopperListToAdd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success!!  Instead of creating a list of objects, which I then loaded into a BindingList(Of T), I just loaded each code object directly into the BindingList, and then set that to a Binding Source, and used that to populate the DataGridView.  Here's my changed code:

The BindingList declaration:

```
Friend masterHopperList As New BindingList(Of IHopperItem)
```

The function (now a sub) to add to the BindingList:

```
Public Sub concatHopperArray(ByRef masterHopperList As BindingList(Of IHopperItem), ByVal hopperListToAdd As List(Of IHopperItem))

'folds a List(Of IHopperItem) into a BindingList


For i = 0 To hopperListToAdd.Count - 1
    Dim hopperItem As IHopperItem = New HopperItem
    hopperItem = hopperListToAdd.Item(i)
    masterHopperList.Add(hopperItem)
Next        

End Sub
```

And finally the UpdateDataGridView Function (also now a sub):

```
Public Sub UpdateDataGridView(ByRef datagridView As Windows.Forms.DataGridView)


Dim bindingSource As BindingSource = New BindingSource()

If datagridView.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
    bindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
    datagridView.DataSource = Nothing
    bindingSource.DataSource = Nothing
    datagridView.Refresh()
End If

bindingSource.DataSource = masterHopperList
datagridView.DataSource = GetType(List(Of IHopperItem))
datagridView.DataSource = bindingSource         

End Sub
```

In addition, as @Plutonix mentioned in the comments above, the object needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`